# What is the time complexity of JavaScript's IN operator?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is the IN operator a linear search operation, like the indexOf() array method?

I want to check the presence of a property in an object for each element in an array, using `if (key in obj)`, in order to avoid nesting iterative operations.

I've checked the spec and there is very little information about the IN operator.

Does it iterate over an object's keys, resulting in a linear time operation? Or does it simply attempt a direct lookup of the key, resulting in a constant time operation?

Comment: That would depend on the implementation, but if you need the operation, then you need it. Have you found an actual performance problem related to the `in` operator? Because if there is an issue, `in` wouldn't be the first place I'd look.

Comment: No actual performance problem, I'm just trying to make a solution to a practice problem maximally efficient, and I realized that I have no idea how IN works underneath the hood.

Comment: Property access should be `O(1)`, not a linear search.

Comment: There is no reason why the time complexity for `key in obj` would not be the same as for `obj[key]`.